# Flexbox space-between has extra 1px gap at the end when using calc()

Tags: css, flexbox, css-calc

I was developing a grid system using flexbox's `justify-content: space-between;` and I noticed that on certain screen sizes (about every other pixel) a 1 pixel gap appears at the end of certain columns.

If you start to resize your browser with the example below, you can see the 1 pixel space appearing and disappearing.

**Example**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[class^="col"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.col-12 {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.col-11 {
  flex-basis: calc(11/12*100% - (1.167 - 11/12)*24px);
}

.col-10 {
  flex-basis: calc(5/6*100% - (1.167 - 5/6)*24px);
}

.col-9 {
  flex-basis: calc(3/4*100% - (1.167 - 3/4)*24px);
}

.col-8 {
  flex-basis: calc(2/3*100% - (1.167 - 2/3)*24px);
}

.col-7 {
  flex-basis: calc(7/12*100% - (1.167 - 7/12)*24px);
}

.col-6 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/2*100% - (1.167 - 1/2)*24px);
}

.col-5 {
  flex-basis: calc(5/12*100% - (1.167 - 5/12)*24px);
}

.col-4 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/3*100% - (1.167 - 1/3)*24px);
}

.col-3 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/4*100% - (1.167 - 1/4)*24px);
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/6*100% - (1.167 - 1/6)*24px);
}

.col-1 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/12*100% - (1.167 - 1/12)*24px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
  <div class="col-7">col-7</div>
  <div class="col-5">col-5</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-2">col-2</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working Fiddle so you can resize it more easily.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hcnfkxv/3/)**

***Note:**
I know that I'm doing some crazy stuff with the `calc()`, but even if you just subtract `5px` instead of `(1.167 - 1/12)*24px)` the issue still exists.

Is this a bug with flexbox?

What do I need to do in order to remove the gap at the end of these columns?

Comment: Probably sub-pixel rounding.

Comment: Frankly, I think you might be better off using CSS-Grid

Comment: That is a better option @Paulie_D, but I'm needing to support certain browsers that are not supported by `css-grid`.

Comment: There is not exact way to avoid sub-pixel rounding using CSS. Either make them  become 1px to wide to fit parent, and use `overflow: hidden`, or use a script so you can do the math yourself, and make sure the rounding fit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

I played around with this problem a little bit before coming to a solution. The steps as follows:

First I converted everything to use a standard format

`calc(a/12 * 100% - (7/6 - a/12) * 24px)` where `a = "col number"`

Next I began experimenting with the number to see the actual output without units (of course)

- **1:** -17.6666...
- **2:** -7.3333...
- **3:** 3
- **4:** 13.3333...
- **5:** 23.6666...
- **6:** 34
- **7:** 44.3333...
- **8:** 54.6666...
- **9:** 65
- **10:** 75.3333...
- **11:** 85.6666...
- **12:** 96

Form this we can see three things

- Any number divisible by **3** is a whole number
- The next number ends by repeating `x.3333...`
- The second number ends in `x.6666...`

**Note:** 1 and 2 are special cases and are reversed because their output is actually negative. We can assume that their numbers would be positive in the real world and would fall inline with the others

After that pinpointing the actual issue in the equation was easy:
`a/12 * 100%`

**So the rounding issue is your problem** - i.e. when you use two or more numbers ending in `x.3333...`

### The Fix

We would like these rounding errors not to cascade so we have a few options

1. Add an subtract the values to get some middle number
2. Add some half pixel to decrease the error and hopefully round the issue away (only add half pixel to numbers ending in `x.3333...`)

Examples:

1. `flex-basis: calc((8/12 - 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 8/12) * 24px);`
2. `flex-basis: calc(8/12 * 100% - (7/6 - 8/12) * 24px);`

I went with the first example to give me this repeating code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[class^="col"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.col-12 {
    flex-basis: calc(12/12 * 100% - (7/6 - 12/12) * 24px);
}
.col-11 {
    flex-basis: calc((11/12 - 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 11/12) * 24px);
}
.col-10 {
    flex-basis: calc((10/12 + 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 10/12) * 24px);
}
.col-9 {
    flex-basis: calc(9/12 * 100% - (7/6 - 9/12) * 24px);
}
.col-8 {
    flex-basis: calc((8/12 - 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 8/12) * 24px);
}
.col-7 {
    flex-basis: calc((7/12 + 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 7/12) * 24px);
}
.col-6 {
    flex-basis: calc(6/12 * 100% - (7/6 - 6/12) * 24px);
}
.col-5 {
    flex-basis: calc((5/12 - 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 5/12) * 24px);
}
.col-4 {
    flex-basis: calc((4/12 + 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 4/12) * 24px);
}
.col-3 {
    flex-basis: calc(3/12 * 100% - (7/6 - 3/12) * 24px);
}
.col-2 {
    flex-basis: calc((2/12 - 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 2/12) * 24px);
}
.col-1 {
    flex-basis: calc((1/12 + 1/6/100) * 100% - (7/6 - 1/12) * 24px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
  <div class="col-7">col-7</div>
  <div class="col-5">col-5</div>
  <div class="col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-2">col-2</div>
</div>
```

This *should work* in modern and even most older browsers that support non-rounded `calc`

If you would like to see the second solution just leave a comment and I'll post it.

**Note:** if you can it would be best to use a language like sass or less to perform these calculations as they after rounding and also functions to keep all this hard work in one place.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is with col-3 and col-6

before:

```
.col-3 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/4*100% - (1.167 - 1/4)*24px);
}
```

after:

```
.col-3 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/4*100% - (1.167 - 1/4)*25px);
}
```

try it:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[class^="col"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.col-12 {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.col-11 {
  flex-basis: calc(11/12*100% - (1.167 - 11/12)*24px);
}

.col-10 {
  flex-basis: calc(5/6*100% - (1.167 - 5/6)*24px);
}

.col-9 {
  flex-basis: calc(3/4*100% - (1.167 - 3/4)*24px);
}

.col-8 {
  flex-basis: calc(2/3*100% - (1.167 - 2/3)*24px);
}

.col-7 {
  flex-basis: calc(7/12*100% - (1.167 - 7/12)*24px);
}

.col-6 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/2*100% - (1.167 - 1/2)*25px);
}

.col-5 {
  flex-basis: calc(5/12*100% - (1.167 - 5/12)*24px);
}

.col-4 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/3*100% - (1.167 - 1/3)*24px);
}

.col-3 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/4*100% - (1.167 - 1/4)*25px);
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/6*100% - (1.167 - 1/6)*24px);
}

.col-1 {
  flex-basis: calc(1/12*100% - (1.167 - 1/12)*24px);
}
```

Comment: it would be good to at least highlight what did you change in your code to make it easier for us to find

Comment: .col-3 and .col-6

Comment: doesn't use  `border: 2px solid red;` use background color border adds 2 pixels